# Dynamic CSS padding for Google +1 button

Tags: css, google-plus-one

I have several Google +1 buttons on my website and when a button is clicked a certain amount of times the plus one button on the page becomes wider and therefore moves out of its space given. How could I stop this from happening dynamically?

The CSS code for the button is as follows:

```
.news-plusone { 
    float: right;
    margin: 2px -20px 0 10px;
}
```

The second parameter in the margin is the one that needs to change dynamically.

Example: http://www.nblackburn.me/index.php?section=news

The +1 button is included in this segment of HTML on my website (formatted here to remove scrolling):

```
<span class="news-plusone">
 <g:plusone size="small" href="http://example.com/"></g:plusone>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Publishers may not alter or obfuscate the +1 Button, and Publishers
>   may not associate the +1 Button with advertising content, such as
>   putting the +1 Button on or adjacent to an ad, or placing ads in
>   shared content, unless authorized to do so by Google. Publishers also
>   may not place in shared content any text, image, or other content that
>   violates the Google+ project's User Content and Conduct Policy.

[+1 button policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html)

However if you were just changing the positioning of the button then possibly showing an example would help clarify your issue.

Comment: Key statement being ***Publishers may not alter*** *or obfuscate the +1 Button*

Comment: i am not altering the button in any way, nor did i say i was. I was changing the position of the button which would be stupid if that was not allowed.